# Overwrite WordPress Plugin Class Function

Tags: plugin-development, oop

I just want to customize the inline style of the div-element. The function looks like this:

```
class class_eqw_product{
   //other code here
     function add_loop_enquiry_button() {
    global $product;

    if(!$this->showButtonOnLoopPage($product)) return;

    $style = self::styleLoopPage();

    if($product->is_type('variable') ){
        echo '<div style="margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; width:100%;">
        <a class="button pi-custom-button add-to-enquiry-loop" href="'.$product->get_permalink().'" '.$style.'>'.esc_html($this->add_to_enquiry_text_loop).'</a>
        </div>';
    }else{
        echo '<div style="margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; width:100%;">
        <a class="button pi-custom-button add-to-enquiry add-to-enquiry-loop" href="javascript:void(0)" data-action="pi_add_to_enquiry" data-id="'.$product->get_id().'" '.$style.'>'.esc_html($this->add_to_enquiry_text_loop).'</a>
        </div>';
    }
}
//other code here
}
```

Is it possible to revise the function in the functions.php

If you could help me further, I would be very grateful.

I look forward to your message.

Best regards
Thomas

Comment: Where did this code come from? Is it your own code, custom code someone's written for your site, or a third-party plugin? Are you asking if it's safe to edit this code yourself (which depends if this code gets auto-updated), or are you asking the authors to add a hook for you to add styles, or something else? Would it be possible to add the style via CSS instead to avoid editing the code here?

Comment: There's nothing in the code you've shared that suggests that you can replace or modify it. To do that it would need to include a [hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/). It's possible that a hook exists at a higher level than what you've shared, but it's impossible to say from what can be seen here. If you want to modify the behaviour of a third party theme or plugin you should contact its author for assistance or developer documentation. Third party plugins are off topic here,

Comment: Yes. Seriously that's the answer. Welcome to WordPress Development. I suggest that you change your question a little from "is this possible?" to something along the lines of "I want to do X, I've done Y, and I got Z." If we know what you are trying to do and where you got stuck, someone may have a solution for you.

Comment: @JacobPeattie thanks for the hint I will contact the plugin developer :)